# Distance between two objects that should not touch: separation or clearance?

Tags: word-choice, difference, synonyms

I have two objects (not people) that should not touch each other and so I need to verify that the distance between the first object and the second object is greater than a certain threshold.

I can generically speak about their *distance* but I would like to use a more specific word and after some research I found *separation* and *clearance*: what is the best?

Comment: I think you mean they should not touch **each other**

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context, but I would use **gap**

Example: "Please ensure a gap between the the TV and the wall"

Clearance is also fine, but it is more of an engineering term

Comment: To me clearance sounds natural too, but implies movement — i.e. I'd leave a gap if placing the TV next to the wall, but I'd allow 6in clearance if moving the TV through a door.